# Why can't I get an Avatar of the Vengeful Monkey?

Tags: bloons-td-6

I play BTD6 on mobile and I got the "There can only be One" monkey knowledge and I wanted to get an Avatar of the Vengeful monkey but it hasn't worked any of the times I tried it. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nam2cSLfuHU) where he summoned the vengeful monkey and followed his exact steps.

First I went into a challenge to make sure I knew what I was doing and I summoned him successfully. Then I played Candy Falls on easy to try and get it in an actual game but that's where I had some trouble. I put a Monkey Buccaneer and got him to 0-2-2 so he would be able to hold off the balloons for a while, then I put down Benjamin for the extra money.

I got a super monkey to 3-0-2 so he would be ready for the sacrifices, then I put down a cannon, a sniper, and an alchemist near by and put around 12 banks around the map to help me get the money faster, then I upgraded my bomb tower to 5-0-2, my sniper to 5-0-2, and my alchemist to 2-5-0, just like he did in the video.

Since I got all the upgrades needed I upgraded my sun avatar to a sun temple and re-did the process from above this time adding a 2-5-0 monkey village and placing a 0-5-2 super monkey and a 2-0-5 super monkey outside the sacrifice radius. At this point it was around round 120-130 and I upgraded to a sun god but for some reason my other 2 super monkey's didn't get sucked in and I didn't get an Avatar of the Vengeful monkey.

Did I do something wrong? I'm 100% sure I had monkey knowledge on because I was depositing money in my banks and I triple checked that all my towers were fully upgraded before I sacrificed them. How do I get an Avatar of the Vengeful Monkey?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the explanation of the steps you gave in this answer and combing slowly through the whole tutorial video, it seems like you did everything right and followed all the steps that were necessary to summon the Avatar. Therefore, there must have been some technicality that went wrong.

- **You may have had incorrect tower placement**. Were the [Anti-Bloon](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/The_Anti-Bloon) (x-5-x) and the [Legend of the Night](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_the_Night) (x-x-5) *definitively* placed out of the sacrifice radius of the Sun Temple when you upgraded it to a Sun God?
- **You might be playing on an outdated game version**. Are you playing on a version of the game that is 3.0+, the version where they added the Avatar of the Vengeful Monkey?
- **Maybe your tower values weren't correct.** Were your tower values possibly discounted so that they didn't add up to enough sacrifice cost?

[According to the wiki entry,](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar_of_the_Vengeful_Monkey) the third problem of having discounted tower values is very common, and may result in a failed summon.

> Bear in mind that some towers may be discounted around the newly upgraded Sun Temple, especially if you have sacrificed Support towers, so ensure the sell prices of each category sum up to more than $35,000 (or more than $37,500 with the Better Sell Deals MK).

The wiki also notes that if you accidentally have the Anti-Bloon or Legend of the Night within the sacrifice range, it will also fail.

> Outside of the Temple's range, place and upgrade The Anti-Bloon (x/5/x Super Monkey) and the Legend of The Night (x/x/5 Super Monkey); they cannot be sacrificed to the creation of the TSG, otherwise the upgrade to AOTVM will fail.

Comment: I'm certain that the Super Monkeys were outside of the radius and I'm running v22 of BTD6. I'm not too sure about the discount though, it is possible they were discounted and didn't count. I'll try again and double check the sell cost.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that I took to get the tower:
Step 1: Go to the Magic Monkey Knowledge Shop and buy the “Their can only be one” Monkey Knowledge.

Step 2: Buy a Super Monkey and upgrade it to 3,0,2. (Sun Avatar with Ultravision)

Step 3: Buy two other Super Monkeys and put them out of range of the other Super Monkey.

Step 4: Upgrade one of them too 0,5,0 and the other one to 0,0,5. (The Anti-Bloon, and The Dark Champion)

Step 5: Buy 2 Wizard Monkeys and put them next to the main Super Monkey. (Sun Avatar with Ultravision)

Step 6: Upgrade one of the Wizard Monkeys to a 2,0,5 (Prince of Darkness with Arcane Blast), and the other one to a 5,0,2 (Archmage with Monkey Sense)

Step 7: Buy 3 Sniper Monkeys and put them next to the main Super Monkey.

Step 8: Upgrade one of them to a 2,0,5 (Elite Defender with Large Calibre), one of them to 2,5,0 (Elite Sniper with Large Calibre), and the last one to a 5,0,2 (Cripple MOAB with Even Faster Firing)

Step 9: Buy a Glue Gunner and put him next to the main Super Monkey.

Step 10: Upgrade the Glue Gunner to 2,0,5 (Super Glue with Corrosive Glue)

Step 11: Buy a Bomb Shooter and put it next to the main Super Monkey.

Step 12: Upgrade the Bomb Shooter to a 5,2,0 (Bloon Crush with Missile Launcher)

Step 13: Upgrade the main Super Monkey to a 4,0,2 (Sun Temple with Ultravision)

***If done correctly there will be 2 golden places circling around the tower***

Step 14: Repeat step 5-12.

Step 15: Buy 2 Spike Factories and put it next to the main Super Monkey.

Step 16: Upgrade one of the Spike Factories to a 0,5,2 (Carpet of Spikes with Directed Spikes), and the other one to a 0,2,5 (Perma-Spike with Even Faster Production)

Step 17: Upgrade the main Super Monkey to a 5,0,2.

Answer (score 0):

It must be in the real game not sandbox. You need to start by get monkey  knowledge point (there can only be one) then get alot of banana farms or merchant men (monkey buccaneer). Use that money to get a sun avatar and put a monkey at value of 50,000$+ from the categories of primary military and magic and sacrifice to the sun temple. Once you have done that you need to get monkeys from all categories (excluding heroes) valued at 50,000$+. Then get legend of the night and anti bloon out of sacrifice radius then sacrifice and if it worked you will see legend of the night and anti bloon be abducted by a beam of light and be absorbed by the true sun god. If you want evil adora follow all the steps previously stated and get adora in range of sun temple and at level 20 and purchase true sun god. (Heroes can't be sacrificed by temple or true sun god)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can’t summon it in sandbox or challenges.

Comment: Please elaborate. Why?